# How to move LinkedList element values into arrays and putting array elements into a linkedlist

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, linked-list

i have a project that uses linkedlists and arrays to create matrices and vectors that are commonly seen in mathematics. I was wondering how you could take the values of linkedlist nodes and store them in an array. The project asks to move elements from a linkedlist Matrix(SparseMatixLinkedList), as the matrix is formed through the construct of an array, and move its values into an array to make it a Matrix through the construct of an array (DenseMatrix).

Would anybody know how to do this, and vice-versa if i wanted to move the elements in the array matrix back into the linkedlist matrix? (The SparseMatrix and DenseMatrix methods are below the commented phrase 'for app 5').

```
import java.util.*;



interface Matrix
{



    Vector VecArray[][] = new Vector[]{

    // Assign the value x to element i,j
    public void set(int i,int j, double x){

        for(int i =0; i < data.length; i++){
    data[i] = x;    
        }
    }
//    i = data [i][i];
    // get the value of the element i,j
    double get(int i, int j);
    // Extract the diagonal of the matrix
    double[] getDiagonal();
    // get the size of the matrix-- number of rows 
    public int getSize(){
        this.size = size;
        return size;
    }
        int count = 0;
//    for (RowNode r = head; r != null; r = r.next){
//      count++;
//    }
    return count;
    }

    // get the number of non-zero elements
    int getNnz(){
        int i;
        int j;
        int [][] aElements = new int [i][j];

        for (int k = 0 ; k < aElements.length; k++){
        int x = aElements.length;
        int y = aElements[0].length;

        int result = x * y;

        return result;
        }

    }
    // Multiply a matrix by a vector
    Vector multiply(Vector B);


    public static int[][] multMatrix(int a[][], Vector B){//a[m][n], b[n][p]
           if(a.length == 0) return new int[0][0];
           if(a[0].length != B.length) return null; //invalid dims

           int n = a[0].length;
           int m = a.length;
           int p = B.getSize();
//         int ans[][] = new int[m][p];


           double[] newV = new double [B.getSize()];

           int value;
           for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                value = 0;
                for(int j = 0;  j < m; j++){
                   value += a[i][j] * B.get(i); 
                }
                newV[i] = value;
            }



//         for(int i = 0;i < m;i++){
//            for(int j = 0;j < p;j++){
//               for(int k = 0;k < n;k++){
//                  ans[i][j] += a[i][k] * B[k][j];
//               }
//            }
//         }
//         return ans;
//         }
//      }

//    Vector A;
//    Vector B;
//    for(int i = 0; i < VecArray.length; i++){
//      for(int j = 0; j < VecArray.length; j++){
//          
//          Vector k = A * B;
//      }
//    }
    // Print matrix using a specific format  
    public void display();

    for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < x[row].length; column++) {
            System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("This is the first array");
        display(firstarray);

        System.out.println("This is the second array");
        display(secondarray);

    // return info about the matrix 
    void info();

    //List<Double> SparseMatrixLinkedList = new LinkedList<Double>(Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0)); 
}




//////////////////////////////////// ARRAY DENSE MATRIX IMPLEMENTATION

class DenseMatrix implements Matrix
{
    //////// TO COMPLETE--you can uncomment the instructions below

    private int size=0; // size of the matrix- number of rows/columns
    private int nnz=0;  // number of non-zero elements
    private double[][] data;



    public DenseMatrix(int n) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }







    /////// return info about the matrix
     public void info(){
        System.out.println("Dense Matrix n="+size+", nnz="+nnz+", Storage="+(8*size*size)+"b or "+(8*size*size)/(1024*1024)+"Mb");
    }


}



//////////////////////////////////// Linked-List SPARSE MATRIX IMPLEMENTATION
//public RowNode rArray[] = new RowNode (100){
//  
//public ColNode cArray[] = new ColNode (100){
//  
//}

data[][] = new Object [RowNode] [ColNode];


class RowNode{
    public    int rowindex;
    public    ColNode col;
    public    RowNode next;

    RowNode(int i){rowindex=i; col=null; next=null;}
}

class ColNode{
    public    double entry;
    public    int colindex;;
    public    ColNode next;

    ColNode(int j,double x){
    colindex=j;
    entry=x;
        next=null;}
}



class SparseMatrixLinkedList implements Matrix
{ 
    List<RowNode> r1 = new LinkedList<RowNode>();
    Node c1 = new LinkedList <ColNode>();
//  int l;
//  if(Link l : r1){
//      l = new LinkedList<ColNode>(1,2);
//  }







    private   RowNode top;
    private   int size=0;
    private   int nnz=0;


    // constructors

    // Basic constructor- no element in the list yet
    SparseMatrixLinkedList(DenseMatrix, size, nnz){

        top=null;
        first = newLink;

    } 
    }

//for App 5:
SparseMatrixLinkedList(DenseMatrix, size, nnz){
    LinkedList<SparseMatrixLinkedList> mlinkedlist = new LinkedList<SparseMatrixLinkedList>();

//  (DenseMatrix, size, nnz){
//  top=null;
//  first = newLink;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        mlinkedlist.add(data[i]);

}

DenseMatrix(SparseMatrixLinkedList){
    mArray[] = new DenseMatrix [size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        mArray[i] = new link;
    }
}

Linkedlist S&EMatrix = new LinkedList <Matrix>(nnz, size){

}

    // methods  

    public void vectorArray(){

    }

    public void display(){
    RowNode current = top; //start probe at the beginning
    System.out.println("i");
    while (current!=null) { // until the end of the list
        System.out.print(current.rowindex+" ");
        ColNode jcurrent = current.col;
        while (jcurrent!=null) { // until the end of the list
        System.out.format("==>  (j=%d, a=%.4f)",jcurrent.colindex,jcurrent.entry);         
        jcurrent = jcurrent.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
        current = current.next; // move to next Link
    }
    System.out.println();
    }

    // return info about the matrix
    public void info(){
    System.out.println("Sparse Matrix n="+size+", nnz="+nnz+", Storage="+(8*nnz)+"b or "+(8*nnz)/(1024*1024)+"Mb");
    }


}
```